# How to put div dynamically in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I have a dynamic array as follows:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [student_id] => 8
        [student_name] => A
        [student_class] => 2
        [student_status] => 1
        [class_id] => 2
        [class_name] => C1
        [class_status] => 1
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [student_id] => 10
        [student_name] => B
        [student_class] => 2
        [student_status] => 1
        [class_id] => 2
        [class_name] => C1
        [class_status] => 1
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [student_id] => 9
        [student_name] => C
        [student_class] => 2
        [student_status] => 1
        [class_id] => 2
        [class_name] => C1
        [class_status] => 1
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [student_id] => 11
        [student_name] => D
        [student_class] => 2
        [student_status] => 1
        [class_id] => 2
        [class_name] => C1
        [class_status] => 1
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [student_id] => 4
        [student_name] => E
        [student_class] => 1
        [student_status] => 1
        [class_id] => 1
        [class_name] => C2
        [class_status] => 1
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [student_id] => 6
        [student_name] => F
        [student_class] => 1
        [student_status] => 1
        [class_id] => 1
        [class_name] => C2
        [class_status] => 1
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [student_id] => 5
        [student_name] => G
        [student_class] => 1
        [student_status] => 1
        [class_id] => 1
        [class_name] => C2
        [class_status] => 1
    )

[7] => stdClass Object
    (
        [student_id] => 7
        [student_name] => H
        [student_class] => 1
        [student_status] => 1
        [class_id] => 1
        [class_name] => C2
        [class_status] => 1
    )

[8] => stdClass Object
    (
        [student_id] => 7
        [student_name] => I
        [student_class] => 1
        [student_status] => 1
        [class_id] => 1
        [class_name] => C2
        [class_status] => 1
    )

[9] => stdClass Object
    (
        [student_id] => 7
        [student_name] => J
        [student_class] => 1
        [student_status] => 1
        [class_id] => 1
        [class_name] => C2
        [class_status] => 1
    )

)
```

What I want is, format it as follows using PHP

```
<div class="main_wrap">
    <h2>C1</h2>
    <div class="inner_wrap">
        <p>
            <span>A</span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <span>B</span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <span>C</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="inner_wrap">
        <p>
            <span>D</span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div> 

<div class="main_wrap">
    <h2>C2</h2>
    <div class="inner_wrap">
        <p>
            <span>E</span>
        </p>
        <p> 
            <span>F</span>
        </p>
        <p> 
            <span>G</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="inner_wrap">
        <p>
            <span>H</span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <span>I</span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <span>J</span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know how to loop it using foreach but having no idea of how to wrap using div dynamically.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23wp5pLj/)

Comment: can you place these code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Where's your php code?

Comment: @HarshSanghani http://jsfiddle.net/23wp5pLj/

Comment: @LeoTAbraham why are you putting different layout for each par like "C1" and "C2". "C1" have only 2 column and "C2" have 3 column. http://prntscr.com/97fqsp

Comment: @Jalpa These values are dynamically generated. Each class can have values ranging from 0 to n. As a result it have have m number of columns as well. Each colum having 3 values.

Comment: Why are D and H, I, J given their own parent `<div>`?

Comment: @LloydBanks There is wrap running for each class here. The div is having class main_wrap. The div inner_wrap is a div having 3 elements each.

Comment: So just to confirm - the array should be sorted by class and then name. Each class has it's own `main_wrap` and you need an `inner_wrap` each for every 3rd students.  Is your problem string handling? sorting?

Comment: @brianlmerritt Sorting is not an aspect here. Each class has it's own main_wrap and you need an inner_wrap each for every 3rd students. This is the only thing I need.

Comment: @LeoTAbraham is your array has sorted class names and student names? Does it have to be in any sort order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is what you are looking for. My solution employs the use of a storage array, and `array_chunk()` to split the sub array in groups of 3, then `implode()` to create the html:

```
// Storage array
$sections   =   array();
// Loop through your large array (I am calling it "all")
foreach($all as $rows) {
        // Store the class title
        $cName              =   $rows->class_name;
        // Store name (and whatever else you want)
        // You could store the key for the original object
        // so you can reference back on the next loop below
        $sections[$cName][] =   $rows->student_name;
    }
// Loop through the store
foreach($sections as $key => $values) {
        // Chunk down to whatever grouping you want (3 is what you mention)
        $grp    =   array_chunk($values,3);
        // Use implode for the chunks
        echo '<div class="main_wrap">'.PHP_EOL.'<h2>'.$key.'</h2>'.PHP_EOL;
        foreach($grp as $values) {
                echo '<div class="inner_wrap">'.PHP_EOL;
                echo "\t<p>".PHP_EOL."\t\t<span>".implode("</span>".PHP_EOL."\t</p>".PHP_EOL."\t<p>".PHP_EOL."\t\t<span>",$values)."</span>".PHP_EOL."\t</p>".PHP_EOL."</div>".PHP_EOL;
            }
        echo '</div>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
```

**Should give you *(or at least it gives me)*:**

```
<div class="main_wrap">
<h2>C1</h2>
<div class="inner_wrap">
    <p>
        <span>A</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>B</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>C</span>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="inner_wrap">
    <p>
        <span>D</span>
    </p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="main_wrap">
<h2>C2</h2>
<div class="inner_wrap">
    <p>
        <span>E</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>F</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>G</span>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="inner_wrap">
    <p>
        <span>H</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>I</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>J</span>
    </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Note, you can fool around with formatting, but it should be the same layout, but tab-wise you will have to add a couple in.

> **ALSO NOTE:** I have not done any checks (like `empty()`) so if the object is not filled or what-have-you, there will be a `foreach()` warning.

Comment: The answer was not fully correct as per my requirement but it helped me to solve the problem. So I am marking it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you need to create parent and child relation between node,like below

```
$book = array();
$book[0] = new stdClass;
$book[0]->id = "1";
$book[0]->student_name = "A";
$book[0]->parent_id = "0";

$book[1] = new stdClass;
$book[1]->id = "2";
$book[1]->student_name = "B";
$book[1]->parent_id = "1";
```

then create tree structure array for this and render as you want.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [student_name] => A
            [parent_id] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [student_name] => B
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [data] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [data] => stdClass Object
                (
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [student_name] => C
            [parent_id] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [student_name] => D
                            [parent_id] => 3
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [data] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [data] => stdClass Object
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Why are you nesting students?  Shouldn't it just be one array with multiple students?

Comment: I am just grouping array based on class name ,so it will easy to iterate on UI.

Comment: I think the requirement is to write the PHP to generate the DIVs, not to change the structure of the data.

Comment: I have seen that he is creating div dynamically based on student class group, so i m just providing a option to crate dynamically div based on group class name,I think process array on PHP model class better than process array on UI.